# Как сделать конфигурируемый std::map

Tags: c++

Какой самый простой способ в плюсах сделать такую штуку:
есть `std:map` (на данный момент case sensitive, как первый вариант ниже), надо в зависимости от опции в конфиге (читается в рантайме), использовать или

```
std::map< std::string,SO<DLayerWithAttributes> > LayerMapType;
```

или

```
std::map< std::ci_string,SO<DLayerWithAttributes> >    LayerMapType;
```

где

```
typedef std::basic_string<char, ci_char_traits> ci_string;
```

а

```
struct ci_char_traits : public std::char_traits<char> { 
    тут переопределены функции, чтобы сравнение было case-insensitive
}
```

?

Comment: делаете my_string (и всегда его используете) и my_char_traits в котором, в зависимости от опции в конфиге вызываете или дефолтную функцию сравнения или свою, регистронезависимую.

Comment: Ну а проще, подсовывая свой компаратор самому map в котором, или сравнивать регистро-независимо или регистро-зависимо: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map - третий параметр шаблона. Имхо, проще - т.к. написать один компаратор быстрее чем два вспомогательных класса (точнее один и один typedef).

Comment: @MonahTuk Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, да мне кажется, что вопрос больше дискуссионный. Но ок.

Answer (score 1):

Вижу два варианта.

Первый - основан на вашем решении: делаете my_string (и всегда его используете) и my_char_traits в котором, в зависимости от опции в конфиге вызываете или дефолтную функцию сравнения или свою, регистронезависимую.

Второй - использовать свой компаратор непосредственно для map, в котором, в зависимости от параметра, вызывать или регистро-независимую или регистро-зависимую версию функции сравнения: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map - третий параметр шаблона. Такой вариант, скорее всего, будет проще, т.к. написать один компаратор потребуется меньше усилий, чем все трейты.

Сам компаратор может быть каким-нибудь таким:

```
...   
bool        ignoreCase = false;    
...
struct string_less
{
    bool operator()(const std::string &x, const std::string &y) 
    {
        return ignoreCase ? tolower(x) < tolower(y) : x < y;
    }
};
```

Comment: спасибо!

Дело в том, что я правлю существующую библиотеку, и описанные классы (ci_*) уже есть, только не используются. Поэтому хотелось бы выбрать концептуально более правильный вариант - код библиотеки красив, не хотелось бы туда заплатками гадить. :)

Comment: LayerMapType - эти сущности уже внутри библиотеки? Или снаружи? В рантайме параметры шаблона уже не поменяешь, а флажка готового у map нет, что бы сменить компаратор. Можно ещё сделать специализацию шаблона std::less для std::string, а там уже, в зависимости от опций, кастовать аргументы к ci_string и делать или такое сравнение или эдакое. При этом изменять код в самой библиотеке не придётся. Но, по сути, это подвариант второго варианта.

Comment: LayerMapType - внутри. Да, я, наконец, осознал всю картину, спасибо большое!

Comment: Лучшее спасибо... ну вы вкурсе :)